# Explanation of output

Tags: java, output

My program

```
class Building {
Building() {
    System.out.print("b ");
}

Building(String name) {
    this();
    System.out.print("bn " + name);
}
};

public class House extends Building {
House() {
    System.out.print("h "); // this is line# 1
}

House(String name) {
    this(); // This is line#2
    System.out.print("hn " + name);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new House("x ");
}
}
```

We know that compiler will write a call to `super()` as the first line in the child class's constructor. Therefore should not the output be:

`b` (call from compiler written call to super(), before line#2

`b` (again from compiler written call to super(),before line#1 )

```
h hn x
```

But the output is

```
b h hn x
```

Why is that?

Comment: House(x) -> this() (House())  -> Building ()

Comment: It wouldn't make much sense, either, if the `super()` constructor was called more than once - and this would probably also be a violation of Java's contract for constructors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a constructor starts with a call to another constructor (either `this` or `super`), the compiler does not insert a call to the superclass's default constructor. Thus, the calls tree is:

```
main
 \-> House(String)                (explicit call)
      |-> House()                 (explicit call)
      |    |-> Building()         (implicit call)
      |    |    |-> Object()      (implicit call)
      |    |    \-> print "b "
      |    \-> print "h "
      \-> print "hn x"
```

Comment: Thanks. Any place where I can read more about this? say Standard or something? Want to know the reason behind that.

Comment: @Anon - It's all spelled out in great detail in [Section 8.8 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8). Be prepared for a lot of dense material. A more gentle introduction (with some details missing) is available in the [Java tutorial on inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Comment: thanks. Last question (only asking because some commentator has brought doubt over my understanding) implicit call to super would be before line#1 or line#2 ?

Comment: @Anon - The implicit call to `super()` is before line #1. The compiler never inserts a superclass constructor call if the constructor starts with a call to another constructor (of any kind, either `this` or `super`). Also, if constructor x is going to call constructor y, the call to y must be the first statement in the body of x.

Answer (score 3):

As per [JLS 8.8.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.6)

> If a constructor body **does not begin with an explicit constructor**
>   invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the
>   primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins
>   with a superclass constructor invocation "super();"

Comment: Thanks but my question in effect is, why is super() called only once

Comment: @Anon: Because you have explicit constructor call this() at line2, if no explicit constructor call, then only implicit call super() will happen. Please read the text JLS one more time.

Answer (score 1):

Your `House(string name)` constructor calls `House()`, which in turn calls `Building()`. `Building(string name)` is never called.

If you wanted to explicitly call `Building(string name)`, in your `House(string name)` constructor you could add this: `super(name);` instead of `this();`

Comment: Yes, I know Buidling (String name) would never be called, I never even mentioned it would be so. My question is something different.

Comment: Sorry I missed where you placed `// this is line #1` and was just using your code as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the visual contol flow of your code:

```
new House("x ")---> House(args)---> House() --->Building()--->Object()
                               ^^this()    ^implicit      ^implicit super() call 
                                             super()
                                             call
```

**---> stands for invoking**

**Output:** `b(from building no-args), h(from no-args House), hn x (from args House)` 
                b h hn x

> From what I know, implicit call to super should be before this(),
>   right? Line#2, in my code

**EDIT:**

The first line in the constructor is either a call to super class constructor using super() or a call to overloaded constructor using this(). if there is a call to overloaded constructor using this() there will be no call to super().

Comment: From what I know, implicit call to super should be before this(), right? Line#2, in my code

Comment: @Anon nope, if you call an overloaded cons explicitly, there will be no super() call in that constructor, check my edit.

Comment: Thanks. Learned something new. +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
House(x) -> House() + "hn" + "x"
            Building() + "h" + "hn" +"x"
            "b" + "h" + "hn" + "x"
```

The call to the superclass will be called only once.

If you want `Building(string name)` to be called, you have to call it explicitly.

I think it could be easier for you to use `super()` instead of `this()`

Comment: I think I understood now. I have another question - why is call to super made only once?